# Регулярное выражение для разных URL

Tags: php

Какое регулярное выражение способно охватить 6 вариантов написания URL?

```
$text = 'Our sites: example.com, www.example.com, http://example.com, https://example.com, http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com.';
$pattern = '# regular expression #';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, вам подойдёт [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3904514/1597497) из англоязычного StackOverflow:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Вдобавок на эту тему есть [целая статья](https://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)

Comment: Вы не знаете, почему в результате выполнения данного выражения, помимо совпадений, в итоговом массиве создаются 4 пустых массива? Пример: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d36be59ca84cc8c796709331bf73598625b7029